[Bug]: Electron .pkg throwing JS error when installed through TEST FLIGHT
Electron Version
19.0.3
What operating system are you using?
macOS
Operating System Version
Sonoma 14.5
What arch are you using?
arm64 (including Apple Silicon)
Expected Behavior
Application is working properly with .dmg but giving JS error.
Note: I have uploaded .pkg signed using transporter and downloaded it through Test-Flight
image
Actual Behavior
App should work .pkg same way its working in .dmg format.
any one can suggest me how can I create dev version of mas build
I am following this document
https://gist.github.com/steve981cr/def310670dfd9ed1439bf31cc734f941#step-12-upload-the-pkg-file
Additional Information
I am using electron with react to create my application.
I am using electron-builder to build and create .dmg with Developer ID application certificate & .pkg with Apple Distribution Certificate.
And @electron/notarize to notarize the application and installer.

Hello,
anyone have resolution for this issue?
